# Not able to pass variables from html to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, variables, server

I am building a webserver for school, but I'm running into a few problems. I am running it on an ubuntu virtual machine. However, when I try to retrieve the variables in my JS code it keeps saying 'document is not defined'. Do I need to run some sort of script in my html in order to make this work? Thanks in advance.
This is my JS and html code:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var varRAM = document.getElementByName("ram").value;
var varDisk = document.getElementByName("disk");
var varCpu = document.getElementByName("cpu");

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
fs.readFile('/home/danesh123/js/test.html', function(err, data) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
res.write(data);
res.end("");
console.log('server running at shitty port {}'.format(varRam))
});
}).listen(8080, '172.19.0.1');



<html>
<body>
<h1>HEAD</h1>
<form action="/hello.js">
<p>ram</p>
<input name="ram" type="text" >
<p>disk</p>
<input name="disk" type="text">
<p>cpu</p>
<input name="cpu" type="text" >
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you understand difference between server and client? Where NodeJS code and HTML are executed?

Comment: html is executed at the client, and Nodejs at the serverside.

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
var varRAM = document.getElementByName("ram").value;
var varDisk = document.getElementByName("disk");
var varCpu = document.getElementByName("cpu");
```

are executing in the server as part of your node.js code, not the client. The client is where the `document` object will exist, not the server.

Comment: what is the best way to pass any information from client to server then?

Comment: Posting a form?

Comment: There is no "best" way, but usually the client will make an AJAX request to the server for data and then the server will respond with that data. An AJAX request is initiated by the client (inside your web page code) and then the server has a resource that is invoked and provides an HTTP response of some kind.